# The items on the border of vis js timeline are getting cut / partially visible

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular5, vis.js

I have tried zoomMin zoomMax but it's not working. This issue is only with the corner cases. Increasing width and adjusting padding also doesn't help.

---

[image]

Comment: zoomMin and zoomMax: zoomMin: 1000 * 60 * 60,
  zoomMax: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 31 * 5,

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it can be solved with overflow: visible on the respective divs.